# failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Windows\system32\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll\" ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jvm

I was working on some stuff a few days ago and today I went to open eclipse I got this error:

```
"failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Windows\system32\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll\" "
```

Could someone please help. I have looked over about 20 Stack Overflow things like this and none of them have worked for me.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to do JNI work?

Comment: Why are you running Eclipse with a JRE? Did you install a JDK? Also, are you running on a 32-bit system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your eclipse cannot find a proper JRE. Make sure you have JRE or JDK installed and  `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to a valid JRE installation path. Also note that 32-bit Eclipse will only work with 32-bit JRE and same applies to 64-bit version.

If nothing works you can point Eclipse to JRE manually by editing `eclipse.ini` file. See [this article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) for details.

Answer (score 0):

“Disclaimer I did not find this solution myself. I came across this error message for the second time when installing the android SDK and remembered how to fix it, but don’t remember where I got the fix from so cheers to the guy who figured this one out:)”

The fix is simple locate

C:\Windows\jre

And delete or rename it. Happy Coding!